# Additional PDF Attachment in E-Mail (ABAP)

Tags: email, attachment, abap

I'm currently trying to send the results of a selection via E-Mail, more precisely as an attachment. My goal is to create a XML-File (which works so far) and a PDF, both fed from the internal table in which the selected data is held. The internal table is declared with a custom type. My current code for sending the E-Mail with the XML attachment looks like following:

```
lr_send_request = cl_bcs=>create_persistent( ).

lr_document = cl_document_bcs=>create_document( i_type    = 'HTM'
                                                i_text    = lt_text
                                                i_subject = lv_subject ).

* ----- converting data of internal table so it is suitable for XML
    ...
* -----

lr_document->add_attachment( i_attachment_type     = 'BIN'
                             i_attachment_subject  = 'output.xml'
                             i_attachment_size     = xml_size
                             i_attachment_language = sy-langu
                             i_att_content_hex     = xml_content ).

lr_send_request->set_document( lr_document ).
```

On the web I was only able to find how to convert spooljob (whatever that is :/) into PDF. With functions like that I may be able to solve my problem but then I can't attach the XML anymore.

How can I convert the data of the internal table into a PDF file to attach it to the E-Mail **in the same way I do with the XML**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple way to create PDF:

1. Create report with Smartform and get output in PDF format. [Sample code](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/Convert+Smartform+to+PDF+format)
2. If your system has adobe form license create with adobe form.
3. Use [zcl_pdf](https://github.com/beraadim/zcl_pdf) class for creating native pdf file.
4. Using CONVERT_ABAPSPOOLJOB_2_PDF FM for getting printer spool as pdf (thanks @Sandra Rossi).

If your PDF is simple (not include complex table, vertical text, images, etc) use third option, otherwise try first or second.

Comment: I think the first option would be the best in my case, the sample code was very helpful. But how do I attach the pdf to the email afterwards?

Comment: Same way with xml attachment.

Comment: There's another option which is to create an ABAP list as a spool file, then convert it to PDF, using function module `CONVERT_ABAPSPOOLJOB_2_PDF`. I know there's also a customizing in SCOT to convert automatically attachments into given formats like PDF, but I'm unsure whether it works in your particular case. PS: Option 1 corresponds to function module `CONVERT_OTF_2_PDF`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now implemented the first option and that worked well. However I'm now having trouble finding out how to fill the smartform with the data from my internal table?

Comment: One of sample procedure: https://www.sapnuts.com/courses/core-abap/smartforms/using-tables-in-smartform.html

Comment: @mkysoft not a very good example because it doesn't receive an internal table as parameter, but anyway I couldn't find a better example - @ suimon, in the "form interface" part of the smart form, add a parameter in the TABLES tab, that you'll be able to fill with your internal table.